# JQuery expand collapse with Font Awesome icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Expand and collapse is working but when the list is expanded I would like to change font awesome '+' to '-' vise versa.     **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/u5q9vxLc/4/)**

**Jquery**

```
$('#ulCollapse li ul').hide();


$('.emplist').each(function() {
  // it counts next childs of each parent
  //$(this).find('.empDetails > p#leafCount span').text($(this).next('ul').children('li').length);

  // it counts total childs of each parent
  var childCount = $(this).siblings('ul').find('li').length;

  if (childCount > 0)
    $(this).find('.empDetails > p#leafCount span').append(childCount);
  else
    $(this).find('.empDetails > p#leafCount span').text('');
});


//expand collapse
var plusClass = 'fa-plus-circle';
var minusClass = 'fa-minus-circle';

$('.empDetails p#leafCount').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.empDetails p#leafCount span').on('click', function() {
  var parentDiv = $(this).parents('.emplist').first();
  var nextUl = parentDiv.next('ul');
  nextUl.toggle();
  parentDiv.closest('ul').find('ul').not(nextUl).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggleClass()` to add and remove the `fa-minus-circle` class on the `i` element:

```js
$('#ulCollapse li ul').hide();


$('.emplist').each(function() {
  // it counts next childs of each parent
  //$(this).find('.empDetails > p#leafCount span').text($(this).next('ul').children('li').length);

  // it counts total childs of each parent
  var childCount = $(this).siblings('ul').find('li').length;

  if (childCount > 0)
    $(this).find('.empDetails > p#leafCount span').append(childCount);
  else
    $(this).find('.empDetails > p#leafCount span').text('');
});


//expand collapse
var plusClass = 'fa-plus-circle';
var minusClass = 'fa-minus-circle';

$('.empDetails p#leafCount').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.empDetails p#leafCount span').on('click', function() {
  var parentDiv = $(this).parents('.emplist').first();
  var nextUl = parentDiv.next('ul');
  nextUl.toggle();
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle')
  parentDiv.closest('ul').find('ul').not(nextUl).hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.fa-minus-circle', function() {
  $(this).closest('.emplist').next('ul').find('.fa-minus-circle').removeClass('fa-minus-circle');
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}


/*circle node css*/

.empDetails {
  color: #eee;
  width: 118px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: rgba(83, 139, 184, 0.8);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 120px;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: -45%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: move;
}

.empDetails p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.emp-img img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 125px;
}

.emplist {
  border: 2px solid #538BB8;
  display: inline-block;
}

.emplist,
.emplist .emp-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 120px;
}

.emplist {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.emp-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #ff0;
}

.emplist:hover .emp-hover .infoMore {
  top: 50%;
}

.emplist:hover .emp-hover,
.emplist:hover .emp-hover .infoMore {
  opacity: 1;
}

.emp-hover .infoMore {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-55%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-55%);
  transform: translateY(-55%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.2s;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.emplist:hover .emp-hover,
.emplist:hover .emp-hover .infoMore {
  opacity: 1;
}

.OrgInfo {
  font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="ulCollapse" style="width: 4550px; margin: 0px auto; right: auto; height: 20px; bottom: auto; left: -28px; top: 1px;" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
  <li parent-id="0" li-id="4938" title="Simon Matthews">
    <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
      <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=4938" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
      <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
        <p class="text-center"> <strong>Simon Matthews</strong></p>
        <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>13</span>
          <button title="info" id="btn_empModal0" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li parent-id="4938" li-id="1742" title="Rima Ahmed" class="nodeActive">
        <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
          <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1742" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
          <div id="nodeAct" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
            <p class="text-center"> <strong>Rima Ahmed</strong></p>
            <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>12</span>
              <button title="info" id="btn_empModal1" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
        </div>
        <ul style="display: block;">
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1737" title="Ambika Amin">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1737" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Ambika Amin</strong></p>
                <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal2" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1738" title="Patricia Bagtas">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1738" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Patricia Bagtas</strong></p>
                <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal3" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1745" title="Veronica Cotoranu">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1745" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Veronica Cotoranu</strong></p>
                <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>2</span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal4" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
            <ul style="display: block;">
              <li parent-id="1745" li-id="1734" title="Gloria Rolusta">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1734" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Gloria Rolusta</strong></p>
                    <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal10" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li parent-id="1745" li-id="1757" title="Karla Tenerife">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1757" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Karla Tenerife</strong></p>
                    <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal12" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1746" title="Manaf Hameed">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1746" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Manaf Hameed</strong></p>
                <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal5" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1747" title="Gerald Vinarao">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1747" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Gerald Vinarao</strong></p>
                <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal6" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1754" title="Ahmed Zubair">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1754" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Ahmed Zubair</strong></p>
                <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>1</span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal7" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
            <ul style="display: none;">
              <li parent-id="1754" li-id="1759" title="Clark Reyel">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1759" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Clark Reyel</strong></p>
                    <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal13" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="4524" title="Sarah Street">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=4524" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Sarah Street</strong></p>
                <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>2</span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal8" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
            <ul style="display: none;">
              <li parent-id="4524" li-id="1733" title="Monday Cabales">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1733" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Monday Cabales</strong></p>
                    <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal9" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li parent-id="4524" li-id="1755" title="Madhumita Sahoo">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://192.168.3.130/Focus.Web.Focus8//HRMS/Common/GetEmpPhoto?employeeCode=1755" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Madhumita Sahoo</strong></p>
                    <p id="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal11" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you, but once check this https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/u5q9vxLc/9/

Comment: observe in 3rd level expand last two nodes

Comment: @nani0077, it seems to work fine in third level too. I opened 3rd level closed second level and opened again second level. `+` icon is showing.

Comment: In 3rd level expand 'Ahmed' then expand 'Sarah' now see Ahmed icon, I hope you understand

Comment: @nani0077, I expanded `Ahmed`, then `Sarah`, and I've looked at `Ahmed` icon, which is `-` and I suppose that it should be. So I don't understand where is the problem with the icons.

Comment: In 3rd level expand 'Ahmed Zubair' then expand 'Sarah Street' now see 'Ahmed Zubair' icon, I hope you understand https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/u5q9vxLc/9/

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand if you don't actually explain what the problem is...There's no need for a fiddle, you can take the code from the snippet I posted as an example.

Comment: 1. expand simon
2. expand Rima Ahmed
3. find Ahmed Zubair and expand
4. now expand next to him 'sarah street' now Ahmed Zubair collapsed but still its showing  '-' icon only

Comment: please help me. just run the snippet expand first two nodes then scroll down now expand last two nodes and observe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149364/discussion-between-nani0077-and-ionut).

Comment: just see once defiantly you will understand my problem

Comment: @lonut please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184040/jquery-collapse-expand-with-icons

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggleClass()` for this. Just add the following script to resolve your problem
[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5q9vxLc/6/)

```
//expand collapse
var plusClass = 'fa fa-plus-circle';
var minusClass = 'fa fa-minus-circle';

$('.empDetails p#leafCount').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.empDetails p#leafCount span').on('click', function() {
  var parentDiv = $(this).parents('.emplist').first();
  var nextUl = parentDiv.next('ul');
  nextUl.toggle();
  parentDiv.closest('ul').find('ul').not(nextUl).hide();
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass(plusClass).toggleClass(minusClass);
});
```

Comment: it is working but when we expand another previous one showing '-' only observe at last node

Comment: expand 'Simon' then again expand 'Rima' now directly collapse 'Simaon'  and expand him. now observe the icon

Comment: your problem was related to toggling the icon, which working fine, but it's another issue which is related to your expend/collapse code

Comment: i wand like this https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/8aaq0j4c/5/ @SuperUser

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184040/jquery-collapse-expand-with-icons

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated version. I also have changed the id to classes as you were using multiple elements with same id.

```js
$('#ulCollapse li ul').hide();


$('.emplist').each(function() {
  // it counts next childs of each parent
  //$(this).find('.empDetails > p#leafCount span').text($(this).next('ul').children('li').length);

  // it counts total childs of each parent
  var childCount = $(this).siblings('ul').find('li').length;

  if (childCount > 0)
    $(this).find('.empDetails > p.leafCount span').append(childCount);
  else
    $(this).find('.empDetails > p.leafCount span').text('');
});


//expand collapse
var plusClass = 'fa-plus-circle';
var minusClass = 'fa-minus-circle';

$('.empDetails p.leafCount').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.empDetails p.leafCount span').on('click', function() {
  var parentDiv = $(this).parents('.emplist').first();
  var nextUl = parentDiv.next('ul');
  nextUl.toggle();
  parentDiv.closest('ul').find('ul').not(nextUl).hide();
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass(plusClass).toggleClass(minusClass);
});
```

```css
li{list-style:none;}

/*circle node css*/
.empDetails {  
  color:#eee;
  width: 118px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: rgba(83, 139, 184, 0.8);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 120px;
  
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: -45%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor:move;
}
.empDetails p{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    line-height:15px;
    text-align:center;
}
.emp-img img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 125px;  
}

.emplist{
    border: 2px solid #538BB8;
    display: inline-block;
     
}

.emplist,
.emplist .emp-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  
}

.emplist {
  overflow: hidden;
}


.emp-hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color:#ff0;
}

.emplist:hover .emp-hover .infoMore {
  top: 50%;
}

.emplist:hover .emp-hover,
.emplist:hover .emp-hover .infoMore {
  opacity: 1;
}

.emp-hover .infoMore {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-55%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-55%);
  transform: translateY(-55%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.2s;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.emplist:hover .emp-hover,
.emplist:hover .emp-hover .infoMore {
  opacity: 1;
}

.OrgInfo{
    font-size:15px !important;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulCollapse" style="width: 4550px; margin: 0px auto; right: auto; height: 20px; bottom: auto; left: -28px; top: 1px;" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
  <li parent-id="0" li-id="4938" title="Simon Matthews">
    <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
      <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
      <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
        <p class="text-center"> <strong>Simon Matthews</strong></p>
        <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>13</span>
          <button title="info" id="btn_empModal0" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li parent-id="4938" li-id="1742" title="Rima Ahmed" class="nodeActive">
        <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
          <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
          <div id="nodeAct" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
            <p class="text-center"> <strong>Rima Ahmed</strong></p>
            <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>12</span>
              <button title="info" id="btn_empModal1" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
        </div>
        <ul style="display: block;">
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1737" title="Ambika Amin">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Ambika Amin</strong></p>
                <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal2" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1738" title="Patricia Bagtas">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Patricia Bagtas</strong></p>
                <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal3" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1745" title="Veronica Cotoranu">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Veronica Cotoranu</strong></p>
                <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>2</span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal4" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
            <ul style="display: block;">
              <li parent-id="1745" li-id="1734" title="Gloria Rolusta">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Gloria Rolusta</strong></p>
                    <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal10" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li parent-id="1745" li-id="1757" title="Karla Tenerife">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Karla Tenerife</strong></p>
                    <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal12" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1746" title="Manaf Hameed">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Manaf Hameed</strong></p>
                <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal5" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1747" title="Gerald Vinarao">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Gerald Vinarao</strong></p>
                <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal6" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="1754" title="Ahmed Zubair">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Ahmed Zubair</strong></p>
                <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>1</span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal7" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
            <ul style="display: none;">
              <li parent-id="1754" li-id="1759" title="Clark Reyel">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Clark Reyel</strong></p>
                    <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal13" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li parent-id="1742" li-id="4524" title="Sarah Street">
            <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
              <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
              <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                <p class="text-center"> <strong>Sarah Street</strong></p>
                <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>2</span>
                  <button title="info" id="btn_empModal8" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
            </div>
            <ul style="display: none;">
              <li parent-id="4524" li-id="1733" title="Monday Cabales">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Monday Cabales</strong></p>
                    <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal9" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li parent-id="4524" li-id="1755" title="Madhumita Sahoo">
                <div class="emplist" style="width: 116px; height: 116px;">
                  <div class="emp-img" style="font-size: 13px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="abc" class="img img-circle img-responsive" style="width: 120px;"></div>
                  <div id="" class="empDetails" style="font-size: 13px;">
                    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Madhumita Sahoo</strong></p>
                    <p class="leafCount" style="cursor: pointer;"><span></span>
                      <button title="info" id="btn_empModal11" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs text-center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle OrgInfo" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div !class="emp-hover" style="font-size: 13px;"></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: expand 'Simon' then again expand 'Rima' now directly collapse 'Simaon' and expand him. now observe the icon