# Jquery collapse expand with icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change font awesome icons along with collapse and expand using jquery. I took code from     **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/u5q9vxLc/9/)** there is an issue in 3rd level. For issue please open fiddle and observe at last node named  as 'Sarah Street' expand this then expand 'Ahmed Zubair' now observe 'Sarah Street' is not changed. Could any one help me

**Jquery**

```
//expand collapse
var plusClass = 'fa-plus-circle';
var minusClass = 'fa-minus-circle';

$('.empDetails p#leafCount').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.empDetails p#leafCount span').on('click', function() {
  var parentDiv = $(this).parents('.emplist').first();
  var nextUl = parentDiv.next('ul');
  nextUl.toggle();
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle')
  parentDiv.closest('ul').find('ul').not(nextUl).hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '.fa-minus-circle', function() {
  $(this).closest('.emplist').next('ul').find('.fa-minus-circle').removeClass('fa-minus-circle');
});
```